# Why does SSH work from the command line but not from the SSH config file?

Tags: ssh, command-line, configuration, sshd

I've found that when running `ssh` from the command line on my system is different than running it from the `~/.ssh/config` file. But I'm not sure how to fix it or if its a problem with the program itself.

I have a server (`blueberry.local`) and a client (`xps.local`). Both have a user named `bob`. Both can resolve each-other with the `host` command from either box.

The server is running `sshd` with the following configuration (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`):

```
UsePAM yes
Banner none
AddressFamily any
Port 22
X11Forwarding no
PermitRootLogin no
GatewayPorts no
PasswordAuthentication no
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
PrintMotd no
AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys %h/.ssh/authorized_keys2 /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/%u
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key


KexAlgorithms sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com

LogLevel INFO
UseDNS no
```

And from my client I'm running `ssh` with this configuration (`~/.ssh/config`):

```
Host blueberry.stark.local
  Port 22
  HostName blueberry.local
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/blueberry_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

When running `ssh` from the command line like this:

```
ssh bob@blueberry.local -i ~/.ssh/blueberry_rsa
```

The command works and I can successfully connect via ssh to the server.

However, when running `ssh` from the command line using the client configuration like this:

```
ssh bob@blueberry.local
```

I get an authentication error:

```
bob@blueberry.local: Permission denied (publickey).
```

What's going on here? I've tried to remove configuration properties and the like but it never works.

What's even stranger is that I have another client configuration just like that that works without any issues at all...

Comment: This question is not about programing and appears to be off-topic on Stack-Overflow.

Comment: What exchange would you recommend for this? Personally, I disagree. I don't think it belongs on ServerFault, Unix & Linux, SuperUser, or Ubuntu. This is a popular developer program that appears not to be behaving properly under some conditions. I also believe, based on this answer - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/194702, that this question is valid for this exchange.

Comment: I would recommend moving it to Unix&Linux.

Comment: In itself ssh is not a "developer program" more than an administrator program, a power-user program, etc... Unix&Linux ServerFault, or SuperUser may fit.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely caused by two factors:

1. Based on your example command, your `Host` and `HostName` values are mixed up:

```
Host <this should be what you type on the CLI>
  ...
  HostName <The real hostname of the server>
  ...
```

This means ssh isn't actually going to use any of the configuration you provided. Making the following change should work.

```
Host blueberry.local
  Port 22
  HostName blueberry.stark.local
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/blueberry_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

This is most likely if the following command works with the configuration you posted:

```
ssh bob@blueberry.starlink.local
```

2. If you expected `ssh` to just try all of your private keys until it found the right one, (`~/.ssh/blueberry_rsa`), its likely you haven't added it to your `ssh-agent` (you can confirm by running `ssh-add -L` and check the output.

```
by default ssh will check these paths, then any additional keys in the agent:
~/.ssh/id_rsa 
~/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
~/.ssh/id_ed25519
~/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
~/.ssh/id_xmss
~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

Its likely you only have ~/.ssh/id_rsa in your agent which is what is throwing the
When in trouble, its always helpful to run `ssh -vvv <rest of your command>` to see whats happening under the hood .

Comment: Oh interesting debugging command I'll have to play around with this. Currently don't have access to the system but what to check this out. I also think you have a typo in the third code block `ssh bob@blueberry.starlink.local` I think should be `ssh bob@blueberry.stark.local` correct? Thanks!